# Counting Different unique numbers in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, unique

I want to count the number of different numbers in the matrix other than `-1`. For example the different numbers in the following matrix  are `6` as the different numbers are `8 9 3 5 2 1`

```
   -1  -1  8  9   
    3   5 -1  3
    2   3  3  1
```

How can I do that with `MATLAB` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I. Using [**`unique`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/unique.html)

Use `unique` with its `'stable'` option to keep the order -

```
A1 = reshape(A.',1,[])  %// A is your input matrix
out = unique(A1(A1~=-1),'stable')  %// out is your desired output
```

Output -

```
out =
     8     9     3     5     2     1
```

If you don't care about keeping the order of the unique numbers, you can use `unique` without the `'stable'` option -

```
A1 = unique(A)
out = A1(A1~=-1)
```

which can be converted to a dense one-liner if you are into those -

```
out = nonzeros(unique(A).*(unique(A)~=-1))
```

II. Using **[`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html)**

Use `setdiff` with `'stable'` option to keep the order -

```
A1 = reshape(A.',1,[])  %// A is your input matrix
out = setdiff(A1,-1,'stable')  %// out is your desired output
```

One-liner using default version of `setdiff`, if you don't care about the order -

```
out = setdiff(A,-1)
```

Finally, you can get the count of those unique numbers with `numel(out)`.

Comment: Hei @Divakar, could you explain your code/answer a little bit? What does `unique` do? and `stable`? and the empty brackets in the `reshape` part? -whenever you have time- :)  Thanks! PS: you got my vote of course!

Comment: Hi @SergioHaram! Well the reshape part is to get `A` as a vector with elements taken in row-major order and `stable` option keeps that order of the unique values in that reshaped vector, as it won't be `8 9 3 5 2 1` otherwise. Thanks for the vote as always! :)